# Possible variations in a bilateral symmetric system

Tags: permutations

Can someone shed a light on how to solve something like this?
I've been looking for permutations but so far I found it very confusing.
As I'm not at home atm, I can't reach for my math books either for an answer.
Maybe you can help?

Given:

- a 5x5 grid
- each cell can have 2 possible values: 0 or 1
- each resulting grid "layout" must be bilateral-symmetric ( on the vertical axis )

Question:
What's the number of possible variations?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to consider all possible $3\times 5$ grids, from which you can get a symmetrical $5\times 5$ grid by mirroring the first two columns about the third. Each cell in the $3\times 5$ grid has 2 possibilities, independent of all the others, so the total number of possibilities is $2^{3\times 5} = 32768$.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your very fast and correct answer!
I figured out I could drop 2 columns, but the rest of the calculations was more difficult for me.

Again thanks!